# How to dismiss a dialog and a bottom sheet consecutively?

Tags: flutter

I have a function that displays a bottom sheet. If one item of this bottom sheet is selected it is dismissed using `Navigator.of(context).pop()` and a dialog is shown. If the user taps on the "Cancel" button I want to dismiss the dialog, too, so I tried using `Navigator.of(context).pop()` again. But nothing happens and I get the error message `Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.` I tried deleting the first one and now the dialog can be dismissed by pressing "Cancel" button but the bottom sheet is still there. Ideally was a way to make the app in the current form work but dismissing both at the same time would also be fine.

I would really appreciate any help.

**Edit:** Added code

```
List<Widget> exerciseSelectionItems(BuildContext context, String schoolClassId) {
List<Widget> items = new List<Widget>();
for (var i = 0; i < selectableExercises.length; i++) {
  Exercise currentExercise = selectableExercises[i];
  items.add(
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(currentExercise.icon),
      title: Text(currentExercise.name),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('create_homework'),
            ),
            content: Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context)
                  .translate('create_homework_message'),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Database().addHomework(
                    schoolClassId,
                    Homework(i, DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('cancel'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
return items;}
```

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: Is the dialogue being created from within the modal bottom sheet or from the page that created the bottom sheet?

Comment: The dialog is created from within the bottom sheet.

Comment: The issue is the `context` you are using to dismiss. Seems the `context` used is of a widget that has been disposed. Please share some code.

Comment: If you are closing the modal bottom sheet before cancelling the dialogue then the context has already gone when you try and navigate as a result of pressing the cancel button. Suggest you don't close the bottom sheet until the decision has been made in the dialogue. Then when they press cancel you pop twice or popuntil (not sure on the last bit).

Comment: When a modal bottom sheet is closed it seems to me to behave as if the app has been backgrounded ie. if you use app lifecycle event listeners, inactive and pause events will be triggered. Caused me a few days of grief to debug that.